# How to route to a path with parameters in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a news-feed website with React.js.

How to make a Router with the news ID?
I'm trying something like this:

```
<Route path="/news/:id">
   { ( {id} ) => <NewsPiece newsID={id}/> }
</Route>
```

But it didn't work out. I tried to look it up but didn't find any way convenience.

Below is my App.js being the main file.

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
import Container from './components/Container'
import NewsPiece from './components/NewsPiece'
import Topics from './components/Topics'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <NavBar/>
      <Router>
        <Switch>

          <Route path="/news/:id">
            { ( {id} ) => <NewsPiece newsID={id}/> }
          </Route>

          <Route path="/news">
            <Topics/>
          </Route>

          <Route path="/">
            <Container/>
          </Route>

        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply create a route like this -

`App.js` -

```
...
<Switch>
 <Route path="/news/:id">
  <NewsPiece />
 </Route>
<Switch>
...
```

Now go to your component and access route parameter like this.

`components/NewsPiece`(assuming it's functional component) -  ​

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function NewPiece = () => {
​....
​const { id } = useParams(); // you'll get the id present in URL route parameter
​....
}

export default NewPiece;
```

Explanation - `react-router-dom` provides a hook `useParams` which extracts all the route parameters present and gives us in an `object` with `key-value` pair.

Since you're already getting id from a route parameter you don't need to use extra props `newsID` for this.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to get the route params.

Your route should just be like this.

```
<Route path="/news/:id">
    <NewsPiece/> 
</Route>
```

You will get the value of your param inside the `NewsPiece` component using `props.match.params.id`

Here `id` is the param name you are using.

Comment: It still gives an error of `id is not defined`

Comment: What's the url you are hitting? Does it have the `id` in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
import Container from './components/Container'
import NewsPiece from './components/NewsPiece'
import Topics from './components/Topics'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <NavBar/>
      <Router>
        <Switch>

          <Route path="/news/:id">
            <NewsPiece newsID={id}/> 
          </Route>

          <Route path="/news">
            <Topics/>
          </Route>

          <Route path="/">
            <Container/>
          </Route>

        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If the error still happens comment the `error` msg

Comment: it still gives an error of `id is not defined`

Comment: You havent specified the id ,refer it as a function outside the routing component it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this then

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
import Container from './components/Container'
import NewsPiece from './components/NewsPiece'
import Topics from './components/Topics'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <NavBar/>
      <Router>
        <Switch>

          <Route 
            path="/news/:id"
            component = {NewsPiece newsID={id}} 
          </Route>

          <Route path="/news">
            <Topics/>
          </Route>

          <Route path="/">
            <Container/>
          </Route>

        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If the error still continues . Its a problem with your importing method...